# React native already has Async Storage. Why should I use Redux and Redux Thunk in my react native app?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk, asyncstorage

I have a stupid question but I'm super confused from it. If React Native has Async Storage available, why should one use Redux and Redux Thunk? Why can't we just save all the data in the Async Storage? What is the purpose/benefit of using Redux over Async Storage?

Comment: Async storage is persistent, its purpose to store values between launches of application. Redux is reactive programming concept implementation, not only just as store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are different things and serve different purposes.

Async Storage is a simple key/value store. It only works with strings. So you can do, `AsyncStorage.set("someKey", "someValue")` That's all it does. It's purpose is to save/persist data on the file system of the phone so that it can be used over multiple app sessions (closing and opening the app)

Redux is a full state management solution that allows you to keep any kind of javascript data in memory during the running of the app and have it available anywhere in the app. Think about how in a react-native app two different components cannot easily see and modify each others state, there has to be some way for them to communicate. Basically, Redux helps you do this.

Considering your level of understanding, I would recommend looking into React Context before you tackle Redux. It is a significantly simpler state management solution than Redux. It is included with React/doesn't require a different code structure and will also help you understand the purpose of Redux.

Comment: Async Storage is available all over the app. Why not use it like Redux? We can change the state of our components through that. And yes, I have used React Context too. I know that using it we can make a global state and add functions to it using the provider.

Comment: @HasnainAli Async Storage is strings only and on the filesystem. Redux/Context is in memory and can pass around any data type, functions, etc. Aside from the fact that you'd have to write and maintain all of your own view and state update logic (which is already handled by redux/context) it would be painfully slow. What do you do if you want to pass a function around? String parse and eval it? If you don't understand why this is a bad idea, you're just going to have to trust me. You might want to ask yourself why would so much effort be put into making these systems...

Comment: The first line pretty much cleared it all. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Redux and Async Storage is 2 different concept. To be clear, Redux is the state management and Async storage is like an client database. If you are familiar web development, I can say that Redux is like session storage and async storage is local storage.

It means that Redux is storing the state of app at the time you using it, when the app is killed, all the state in Redux will be deleted. In contrast, async storage store the app' state even if the app is killed.

Therefore, there are a combination of this two. Example: When user first time login to the app, we will store the user info in the async storage so from the next time, user will not be required to login again.

Comment: So what if I use AppState to check if the app is open or not. Once the app is killed, I clear the Async Storage. Basically, I use Async Storage the same way as we use Redux. Can you clear this?

Comment: yeah, you can use that way but get and set method of async storage is asynchronous actions, so be aware about that